# How to get current window URL and use it?

Tags: javascript

I want to get current window location using JavaScript and use it in the following code:

```
<img src="http://shook.eu.org/qrc.php?text=CURRENT_WINDOW_URL" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are building the html from a string:

```js
    var img = '<img src="http://shook.eu.org/qrc.php?text=' + encodeURI(window.location.href) + '" />';

    document.body.innerHTML = img;
```

Edit: You should `encodeURI` the string you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = window.location.href;

var img = '<img src="http://shook.eu.org/qrc.php?text='+url+'" />';

$('#img').html(img);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img"></div>
```